# Share UIImage using FBWebDialogs using Facebook SDK in ios 7

Tags: facebook, uiimage, ios7, sharing, fbwebdialogs

I am trying to share the local UIImage using FBWebDialogs. But I am getting any solution which will share the local image using FBWebDialogs. Can anybody tell me , how can I share local UIImage using FBWebDialogs ? 
Note: My iOS app is totally local. So I can't get the image URL.

Here is my code

```
    -(void)shareInformationUsingFeedDialogWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)params
{
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:@"An error occured while sharing information using Facebook"];
         }
         else
         {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
             {
                 [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Alert" andMessage:@"You cancelled the Facebook sharing"];
             }
             else
             {
                 [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Success" andMessage:@"Facebook sharing successful"];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```